# Python long nested loop

Tags: python, for-loop, nested

I have two nested loop that takes so long. Is there any way that I can make it faster ?

Here is my code :

```
for i in range (start, start+fin):
        for j in range (0, start+fin):
                tuple = ( i, j , matrice[i][j], tf)
                listeA.append(tuple)

for i in range (0, start):
        for j in range (start, start+fin):
                tuple = ( i, j , matrice[i][j], tf)
                listeA.append(tuple)
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'd advise you to name your variables in English, especially in python where the keywords are natural English.

Comment: Why do you put the contents of `matrice[i][j]` into a list? Do you really need to do that? Can't you just loop over your i, j matrix and process the data here?

Comment: Are you trying to iterate over a metrice?

Comment: Nepho, yes I need to put it in a list then it goes in a tuple to be insert in a database.

Comment: @AdamKatav : Yes I iterate over a metrice.That is why it is so long I think.

Answer (score 0):

Not really. They probably take a long time because they iterate a large amount of times.

Answer (score 0):

It's O(N^2), so by nature it's slow on large datasets. You have two very similar loops here, I'm not quite sure why you're iterating over them in this fashion, but there might be a smarter way of getting around that so that you don't have to have two nested loops. Hard to tell without the bigger picture.

That said - using map() or list comprehensions might give you a slight boost over a plain old for.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't need to store the tuple in a variable, you can store it directly into the list.
Second, loop over the matrice once.
Something like:

```
for i in range(vertical):
  for j in range(diagonal):
    listeA = (i, j, matrice[i][j])
```

Change the variables in range() as fit.
Also, in Python it isn't recommended to construct your own data structures. You don't need to reinvent matrices.
You can use [numpy.matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html)